# Bokeh tooltip do not show up

Tags: tooltip, bokeh

Using tooltip in bokeh (1.3.4), tooltips do not consistently show up.
There could be up to 10K points on a chart.

Here is the code:

```
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("Kms", "@kms"),
    ("Price", "@price")
]

hover = HoverTool(tooltips = TOOLTIPS)

plot = figure(
    plot_width=550, plot_height=550,
    x_range=[0, 300000], y_range=[0, 50000],
    tools=[hover], tooltips=TOOLTIPS
)

source = ColumnDataSource(ds)
r = plot.circle(
    x='kms', y='price',
    source=source,
    size=10,
    color='bk_color_sud',
    legend='legend',
    alpha=0.7
)
```

Of course, `ds` is a pandas dataframe which contains columns among which `kms` and `price`.

Anyone would know why no tooltip is displaying?

Comment: You have double `tooltips`: in 'HoverTool' and in `figure`. In your `hover` you don't specify any renderers and this can cause a problem. So I would remove the first `hover` then do `tools="hover"` in figure and then `plot.hover.tooltips = TOOLTIPS` or leave the `tooltips` in `figure` like it is now but provided that there are no more glyphs/renderers in your plot

Comment: it wasn't the issue but your comment hinted at the solution :) I had another renderer below that! Thx a lot